# How to get the underlying type of an IList item?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method that receives an `IList`. Is there a way to get the Type of the items of the `IList`?

```
public void MyMethod(IList myList)
{
}
```

I have a class that you can associate an IList to, you can also add a NewItem function, but I would like to be able to add items with the default empty constructor in case the user didn't set the NewItem function.

How can I get the Type of the underlying items? I would know how to do it if it was an `IList<T>`, but I can't change the API, because I can receive any kind of collection that implements IList, only restriction, that is not enforced by code, is that all the items in the collections we receive are of the same type.

Comment: there is no different way of getting underlying type of List<T> or IList. since they will override the methods. you can do this. `list.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0]` and note that this is the same way when you want to get type of items in List<T>

Comment: Can you assume that `myList` would also implement `IList<T>`?

Comment: What is the underlying collection type the API is sending you as an `IList`?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - for real? I just assumed it couldn't do that.

Comment: @YacoubMassad - Nope :(

Comment: Then how do you know that the items in the list are of the same type? Maybe it contains one integer and one string.

Comment: Or even worse, it might be empty. In this case, nothing can be said about the type.

Comment: @YacoubMassad - Well, In theory they shouldn't be doing that. No one has reported such behavior. I have little control on what people are doing sadly, but although they may be using different collections, they should always be of one item Type.

Comment: Can you assume that the object would implement `IEnumerable<T>` or any generic interface?

Comment: @YacoubMassad - I can't really assume anything, many users, many things we don't know, and can't know :(. But what Jonesopolis is suggesting seems to be on the line I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a heuristic algorithm that you can start with. Most (if not all) generic list interfaces inherit from `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can check if the list implements `IEnumerable<T>`. If it doesn't, you check the type of the first element, assuming of course that the list would contain elements of the same type. If the list is empty, this method returns null.

```
public static Type HeuristicallyDetermineType(IList myList)
{
    var enumerable_type = 
        myList.GetType()
        .GetInterfaces()
        .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1)
        .FirstOrDefault(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IEnumerable<>));

    if (enumerable_type != null)
        return enumerable_type.GenericTypeArguments[0];

    if (myList.Count == 0)
        return null;

    return myList[0].GetType();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since it's an `IList`, you'd first have to check if it is actually generic:

```
if (list.GetType().IsGenericType)
      Console.WriteLine($"Is generic collection of {list.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0]}");
else
      Console.WriteLine("Is not generic");
```

For example, using

```
IList list = new List<string>();
```

would give `Is generic collection of System.String`, and

```
IList list = new ArrayList();
```

would give `Is not generic`

Comment: huh.  SO would benefit from better highlighting of the C#6 string interpolation syntax.

Comment: for applications below .net 4.5, use [Type.GetGenericArguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this have a List and in an additional List add the types.

```
   IList<object> iListObj = new List<object>
   {
        1234,
       "Harold Nelson",
       false,
       'A'
   };
   var typeList = new List<object>();
   foreach (var item in iListObj)
   {
       typeList.Add(item.GetType());
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the types passed are non-generic than you may have a grabbag of types (e.g.):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new ArrayList();
            list.Add("Hello");
            list.Add(0);

            var types = GetTypes(list);

            foreach (var itemType in types)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(itemType.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static HashSet<Type> GetTypes(IList list)
        {
            var types = new HashSet<Type>();

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var newType = item.GetType();
                if (!types.Contains(newType))
                {
                    types.Add(newType);
                }
            }

            return types;
        }
    }
}
```

You would have to make the GetTypes function more complicated to deal with the generic case also.